# Class by index or data-attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have this code:

```
var i = 1;
if ($(this).attr('data-target="1"')){}
```

Now I want to pass i variable instead of 1.

```
if ($(this).attr('data-target="'+i+'"')){}
```

Am i right?

actually what I want to do. I want to click `li` on click of `h2` `data-target` in for loop. Is there any other solution for target multiple elements by one code?

find **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk6uLuze/12/)**

Comment: use `data("target")` instead of `attr(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have element with class `ul`,

Just try this,

```
$('.UDSHead').click(function(){
  var dataTarget = $(this).data('target');
  $('li:eq('+ (dataTarget - 1) +')').addClass('highLight');
});
```

Also, you don't need to bind event in the for loop.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/zk6uLuze/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// if you're using dynamic content for h2, then use .on instead for event delegation issues
$(document).on('click', '.UDSHead', function () {
  // remove class from li element
  $('li').removeClass('highLight');
  // get current element data-target value
  var target = $(this).data('target'); 
  // minus 1 as eq is zero based   
  $('ul li:eq(' + (target-1) + ')').addClass('highLight');    

});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/zk6uLuze/10/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can have single click event for all the h2 elements and then target respective lis based on index of clicked h2:

```
var udsheads = $('.UDSHead');
var lis = $('li');
udsheads.click(function(){
  lis.removeClass('highLight').eq(udsheads.index(this)).addClass('highLight')
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b5tk7sjc/)**

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I like your alternate solution without using data-target.

Comment: @locateganesh: i suggested that because i did not found the data target values from 1-4. the solution provided by others fails on click of 4th h2 element. this will work in all the cases though as its index based :)

Comment: on 4th one.. It was not mistake. I have written data-target="1" instead of data-target="4". Others are also right. But your index in nice..

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs http://api.jquery.com/attr/ if you want to compare an attribute value you have to do it this way:

```
if($(this).attr( attributeName ) == value)
```

Applying to your code:

```
if( $(this).attr('data-target') == i ) {
  // more code
}
```

Using the data function:

```
if( $(this).data('target') == i ) {
  // more code
}
```